# poles of $f(z) /e^{f(z)} $/Question about proof with sequences

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I have a question about the following proofs how $f(z)$ and $e^{f(z)}$ can not have common poles:

> Assume $z_0$ is a pole of $f$, then in a punctured disk near $z_0$ one
> can write $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^{k}}$, g(z) holomorphic and $g(z_0)
>  \neq 0$. Let $g(z_0) = re^{i \theta}$, and $z_n = z_0 + \frac{e^{i
>  \theta/n}}{n}$. Then since $f(z_n)=g(z_n) e^{- i\theta} n^n $ and
> $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(z_n) = re^{i \theta}$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{f(z_n)}
>  = \infty$ So it follows that if $z_0$ a pole, it can not be a removable singularity of $e^f$. Further consider  $$w_n = z_0 +
> \frac{e^{i (\theta+\pi)/n}}{n}$$ and we see that $\lim_{n \to \infty}
>  e^{f(w_n)} = 0$

my question is that when calculating $f(z_n)$ why was the $z_n$ taken to a power of n? and where did $k$ the order of pole go? because I get
$f(z_n) = \frac{g(z_n)}{({\frac{e^{i\theta/n}}{n})}^{k}}$

Comment: @MartinR: deleted them now, they appeared because I had put the whole proof into quotation marks.

Comment: @MartinR: thx, added now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That reasoning is indeed wrong. A better choice is
$$
z_n = z_0 + \frac 1n e^{i\theta/k} \, .
$$
Then
$$
f(z_n) = \frac{g(z_n) n^k}{e^{i \theta}} = \frac{g(z_n)}{g(z_0)} \cdot r n^k
$$
and therefore
$$
 \left|e^{f(z_n)}\right| = e^{\operatorname{Re}f(z_n)}
= e^{ rn^k \operatorname{Re}(g(z_n)/g(z_0))} 
> e^{r n^k/2}
$$
for sufficiently large $n$. This shows that $\lim_{n\to \infty} e^{f(z_n)} = \infty$.

For the second part you would choose
$$
w_n = z_0 + \frac 1n e^{i(\theta+ \pi)/k} \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your checking it and giving the correct reasoning